# Is there some kind of tuple wildcart in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, syntactic-sugar

For instance, in Erlang one can use an usual pattern matching wildcart while reading tuples. Say, I want to read a red channel value from a color. Instead of writing:

```
{R, G, B, A} = color()
```

I could do:

```
{R, _, _, _} = color()
```

'_' here stands for everything I don't care about. This syntax makes code a little bit cleaner on unnecessary variables.

Is there something like this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not per se, since [`_` is a valid variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727167/python-internationalization-gettext). It is possible to unpack the same way though:

```
r, x, x, x = color()
```

3.x lets you not care about the ones on the end all at once:

```
r, *x = color()
```

Or indexing is always an option.

```
r = color()[0]
```

Comment: Since `_` is, as you say, a valid variable name: Why not use it here instead of `x`, which looks like a bug or accidentally unused variable?

Comment: @delnan: Because of its use in i18n.

Comment: I keep forgetting that, good point. However, I do think `_` is preferable is there's no i18n in the code. In any case, `x` seems a pretty bad choice for a "don't care" variable.